# How to update internal state of nginx' module runtime?

Tags: c, nginx

Lets suppose I wish to write a nginx module that blocks clients by IP. 
In order to do so, on initialization stage i read a file with IP addresses 
that I have to block (black list) and store it in module's context.

Now I wish to update the black list without restarting nginx. 
One of the possible solutions, is to add a handler on specific location.
e.g. if uri "/block/1.2.3.4" requested, my handler adds ip address 1.2.3.4 to the black list.

However, nginx runs several workers as separated processes, so only one particular worker will updated.

What is a common pattern to cope such problems?

Comment: Are you able to move the black list outside of the module's context? Perhaps to a system file, a KV store, or SHM? That would allow each process to talk to a central source blacklist.

Comment: But then I need synchronization mechanism too access this shared memory. This may slow down all system.

Comment: Yes, but I believe `shmat()` and futex will do the job and the overhead will be negligible.

Comment: If you are careful about how exactly you update your shared data structure, only your update process needs to lock the data (to prevent concurrent updates). You just have to make sure that from the point of view of a purely read-only access to the data, the data structure stays valid at all times. If you use for example a fixed size hash table, this isn't that hard to do. You can take advantage of the fact that certain operations are atomic (for example, on many architectures, updating a single pointer is as long as the pointer is aligned properly in memory).

Comment: Can you put a hook on nginx reload, and reload your config file then?

Comment: If you are fine with not using nginx module, you can use iptables to block request from blacklisted IP.

Comment: @avip if you write you comment as answer, I will mark it as a solution

Comment: @BorisT Just did that, thank you. If you have a blog, and the code isn't proprietary, I think some people might benefit fro seeing your solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to move the black list outside of the module's context, perhaps to a system file, a KV store, or SHM, that would allow each process to talk to a central source blacklist. I believe shmat() and futex will do the job and the overhead will be negligible.

Answer (score 3):

But nginx does not require a restart (nor any downtime) in order to change the configuration!

See:

- http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html#reconfiguration

> In order for nginx to re-read the configuration file, a HUP signal should be sent to the master process. The master process first checks the syntax validity, then tries to apply new configuration, that is, to open log files and new listen sockets. If this fails, it rolls back changes and continues to work with old configuration. If this succeeds, it starts new worker processes, and sends messages to old worker processes requesting them to shut down gracefully. Old worker processes close listen sockets and continue to service old clients. After all clients are serviced, old worker processes are shut down.

As an administrator, it would be my expectation that all modules would, in fact, be controlled in this way, too.

(Of course, if you require a lot of changes to the configuration very often, a different solution might be more appropriate.)

---

You give an explicit example of blocking access by IP.  Are you sure you require a new module in order to accomplish the task?  It would seem that a combination of the following standard directives might suffice already:

- http://nginx.org/r/deny && http://nginx.org/r/allow
- http://nginx.org/r/geo
- http://nginx.org/r/map
- http://nginx.org/r/if && http://nginx.org/r/return

---